# CMake error HDF5

Tags: 14.04, command-line, compiling, cmake

I´m trying to install a program on Ubuntu. Therefore, I´ve to install OpenMP, Eigen, CMake and HDF5. After compiling all these libraries with Cmake I finally got to the last step: Installing ParOSol

After giving all the commands needed in the terminal it shows:

```
cmake: 138 (message)
   Could NOT find HDF5 (missing: HDF5_LIBRARIES HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS)
```

Any idea how I can tell terminal to find these files? In other forums it is recommended to use:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/hdf5"
```

but it didn´t work.

Cheers

Comment: I don't think `PATH` is involved at all in the search for libraries or include files; the project's `README.mkdn` file suggests using cmake directives `-D HDF5_LIBRARIES:PATH=/path/to/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.so` and `-D HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=/path/to/hdf5/include`

Comment: cmake \ -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=mpic++ \ -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=RelWithDebInfo \ -D HDF5_LIBRARIES:PATH=/path/to/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.so\ -D HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=/path/to/hdf5/include \ ../src                                   this is the command that is the user guide. I´ve just changed the paths to find the libraries in my computer

Comment: FWIW there was no need to build hdf5 from source since 14.04 provides libhdf5-dev 1.8.11-5ubuntu7 (which satisfies the hdf5 > 1.8 requirement)

Comment: That is what I´ve done. I´ve changed just the /path/to part to my actual diretory where the file hdf5 is located on may computer. I´ve done the same with the hdf5/llib/include directory e.g -D HDF5_LIBRRIES:PATH=/home/SebastianGT/CMake-hdf5-1.8.17/hdf5/lib

Comment: OK, thanks I didn´t know that. But still how do I solve the cmake: 138 (message)
   Could NOT find HDF5 (missing: HDF5_LIBRARIES HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS) problem?

Comment: Probably the simplest solution is to install the `libhdf5-dev` package and let cmake find that - it shouldn't be necessary to specify its paths explicitly, just use the default `build/do_configure.sh`

Comment: Thanks! There hasn´t been any problems with HDF5 since then. Now after writting make in the terminal I've got some errors:    `/home/gaetano/parosol/src/main.cpp:126:34:   required from here
/home/gaetano/parosol/src/GenericMatrix.h:186:11: warning: unused variable ‘nu’ [-Wunused-variable]
    double nu = 0.3;
           ^
make[2]: *** No rule to make target` `/Desktop/Sebastian-Godoy-Tercero/CMake-hdf5-1.8.17/build/HDF5-1.8.17-Linux/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.8.17/lib', needed by `parosol'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/parosol.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2`

Comment: It looks like it's still finding stuff in your source-built HDF5 directory? Unfortunately `cmake` aggressively caches stuff - it's often best to start over with a clean tarball (of `parosol` - there's shouldn't be any need to rebuild other prerequisites) so you can be sure that any old configuration variables have been purged.

Comment: Ok then. What do you exactly mean with start over with a clean tarball? Start over uncompressing HDF5 and compiling it again?

Comment: NO, HDF5 should not be an issue now that you have installed the system package for it. I mean start over uncompressing (or git cloning - however you originally obtained it) the source code of parosol, so that when you `cmake` **that** it for sure picks up the system version of HDF5 not your source-built version. And of course **don't** set a non-default `-D HDF5_LIBRARIES:PATH` (or its include path) this time around.

Comment: I did as you suggested and I still get this message with the `unused variable 'nu'` and `Linking CXX executable parosol [100%] Built target parosol`. Should I worry about it?  I ran a mesh test in order to see if it works. After that an error line shows up: `ImportError: No module named h5py`

Comment: You can ignore the unused variable warning. Does the build process provide an install target (e.g. `make install`) and if so did you run it?

Comment: The last command you have to give in order to build Parosol is `make`. After that the software is built in the `build/`directory where you can find a cmake_install.cmake file. I haven´t run any `make install` target

Comment: Hmm.. I can't actually see anything related to python modules/bindings here. Are you sure the software provides them?

Comment: The software ships with some helper tools `/tools`. In this directory there is a python script that generates a xmf which describes how to read the h5 mesh file. It´s also the only .py file found in the parosol directory

Comment: Ah OK I think I understand - in that case, you probably just need to install the `python-h5py` package from the repository

Comment: Hey, after all it all worked well! Thanks for the help! Now I'm facing another problem. I'm installing HDFview on Linux and after starting the configure file an error occured. It says that I've to tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting the environment variable "JAVA_COMPILER" or the CMake cache entre CMAKE_JAVA_COMPILER to the full path to the comiler. I'm working with terminal. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should post that as a separate question imho